# No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@mipmap/ic_chat_black')

Tags: android, xml, mipmaps

When signed an apk got this message

> Error:(6, 23) No resource found that matches the given name

[image: xml code]

(at 'icon' with value '@mipmap/ic_chat_black').

[image: error message]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the filename is correct and that it is in the mipmap folder. You may be using mipmap mistakenly instead of the drawable folder.

Comment: the name is correct, when executed de app in a device its a successful.

but when signed the apk, it return this error

Comment: Check your settings for the release build as it could be causing some issues.